# Solr search t-shirt returns shirt

Tags: solr

When i'm searching for t-shirts on my solr, it returns shirts first.
I configured my field as follows:

```
    <fieldType name="my_test" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer type="index">        
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" maxGramSize="20" minGramSize="2"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">        
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Do you see any optimization point?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory instead of solr.StandardTokenizerFactory

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using the `StandardTokenizerFactory` for your field which is creating a token as shirt and hence a match.

`StandardTokenizerFactory` :-
It tokenizes on whitespace, as well as strips characters

The Documentation for `StandardTokenizerFactory` mentions as :-

> Splits words at punctuation characters, removing punctuations.
> However, a dot that's not followed by whitespace is considered part of
> a token. Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the
> token. In that case, the whole token is interpreted as a product
> number and is not split. Recognizes email addresses and Internet
> hostnames as one token.

If you want to perform search on the "t-shirt", then it should be tokenized.
I would suggest you to use the `KeywordTokenizerFactory`

Keyword Tokenizer does not split the input provided to it.
It does not do any processing on the string, and the entire string is treated as a single token.
This doesn't actually do any tokenization. It returns the original text as one term.

This `KeywordTokenizerFactory` is used for sorting or faceting requirements, where one want to perform the exact match. Its helpful in faceting and sorting.

You can have another field and apply `KeywordTokenizerFactory` to it and perform your search on it.